# Path Filters and Controlling Execution Order of Triggered Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Let's say I have three pipelines that do the following:

- **Pipeline 1**:

  - *Task A*
- **Pipeline 2**:

  - *Task B*
- **Pipeline 3**:

  - *Task A*
  - *Task B*

Now let's say my repo has two directories:

- **AStuff**
- **BStuff**

Is there any way to set path filters such that:

- If **AStuff** has changes but **BStuff** doesn't, **Pipeline 1** runs (and nothing else)
- If **BStuff** has changes but **AStuff** doesn't, **Pipeline 2** runs (and nothing else)
- If both **AStuff** and **BStuff** have changes, **Pipeline 3** runs (and nothing else)

The root of my problem is that I want *Task A* to run if **AStuff** has changes, and I want *Task B* to run if **BStuff** has changes.  But if they both have changes, I would prefer *Task A* runs and then *Task B* runs, instead of ADO selecting whichever one it wants to run first.  So, alternatively, maybe there's some way for **Pipeline 2** to have a triggers/conditions that cause it to run when **Pipeline 1** completes, but only if the changes that triggered **Pipeline 1** affected the **BStuff** directory.

Comment: Hi, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

No built-in feature to achieve your third requirement.

And it is impossible for the third pipeline to run independently, if the third pipeline runs, it must mean that the first two pipelines will also run. Unless the third pipeline is not in the same environment as the first two.

The following pipeline definition should meet your requirements.

**Check_StuffA**

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - AStuff/*
    exclude:
    - BStuff/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

**Check_StuffB**

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - BStuff/*
    exclude:
    - AStuff/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

**Check_StuffA&B**

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - AStuff/*
    - BStuff/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs: 
  - job: check
    displayName: Check changed files
    pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - task: ChangedFiles@1
        name: CheckChanges
        inputs:
          rules: |
            [CodeChanged]
            AStuff/*

            [TestsChanged]
            BStuff/*

  - job: build
    displayName: Build only when code changes
    dependsOn: check
    condition: and(eq(dependencies.check.outputs['CheckChanges.CodeChanged'], 'true'),eq(dependencies.check.outputs['CheckChanges.TestsChanged'], 'true'))
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            # Write your PowerShell commands here.
            
            Write-Host "Hello World"
```

Comment: I had to move to a different area of this project but will return to this soon and attempt to verify.